# AngularUI Modal disabled button pressing

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, button

I have a form in modal window which has disabled submit button until form is valid. Button is transparent and I can't press it with mouse. Unfortunately I am able to press that button by pressing TAB and Space. What can I do to disable button?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I had:

```
<button id="test-button-submit" ng-class="{ disabled: signup_form.$invalid }" ng-click="okEdit()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

This is what I have now:

```
<button id="tet-button-submit" disabled="{{signup_form.$invalid}}" ng-click="okEdit()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

What am I doing wrong? At first it worked fine, but I could press my button with TAB and enter or space. Now my button is always disabled, even my form is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-disabled for that purpose:

```
<button ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}">Disabled</button>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: I've also tried with ng-disabled, result was the same, I have tried to simply ng-disabled="false" and it disabled my button too, I couldn't find out what was the problem.